# WebStorm automatically made jsx tag. How to turn it off?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

When I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key here:

[image]

I'll get the following result:

[image]

How to turn off such a behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

this is the expected behavior with Emmet, see https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/implicit-names/
You can assign a different shortcut to **Expand abbreviation with** in **Settings | Editor | Emmet** to avoid expanding abbreviations once you hit `Enter`

Comment: Thanks, it helps me. I changed the shortcut  from  "Enter" to "Ctrl + Enter" and now I'm very happy)